# php Laravel- A non well formed numeric value encountered (on string)

Tags: php, laravel

I have two function in my controller and service. I want to call a function in service. Here is my code :

**Controller:**

```
public function findNeighborhoodGet(): array
{
    $regionCenter = Request::get('region_center');
    $distanceService = \App::make('App\web\one\Infrastructure\Service\Google\Map');
    try {
        $userPoint = $distanceService->getOriginPoint($regionCenter);
    }
 .
 .
 .
 return $result
}
```

**my service (Map.php) :**

```
public function getOriginPoint(string $origin):Point
{
    dd($origin);

    return $this->getPointObject($origin);
}
```

Actually , I get an error :

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

at this line: 
*public function getOriginPoint(string $origin):Point*

How to solve it?

Comment: what is in `$regionCenter`?

Comment: @Neat "35.792616,51.417127"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a bug in the symfony/var-dumper package when using PHP7.1. It was fixed in version 2.7.16, 2.8.9, 3.0.9 and 3.1.3. See the pull request: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/19379

In my case, I needed to `composer update` my laravel framework packages, as my vendor directory copy of that package was at 2.7.9. (I'm using Laravel 5.1; later versions use 2.8 and 3.0 of symfony, which also had the bug)

Comment: Thanks! I picked up a Laravel 5.1 project the other day and was confused when it didn't work in the newer Homestead VM environment, which has had PHP updated. A `$ composer update` did the trick!

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue on Laravel 5.2 PHP 7.1. If you don't want to update the entire framework, you can do:

```
composer update symfony/var-dumper
```

as stated [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html).